# How does Vanellope von Schweetz actually leave Sugar Rush in Wreck-It Ralph 2?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph, ralph-breaks-the-internet

How does Vanellope von Schweetz actually leave Sugar Rush in *Ralph Breaks the Internet* when it was quite dramatically established in *Wreck-It Ralph* that she can't leave Sugar Rush at all?

Comment: As I haven't saw the film yet I can't tell if this is a spoiler or no, but it certainly feels like it could be (I know I'm a little bit sadder that I now know this fact about Vanellope before it was properly revealed). Could the title be re-worded so as to not give this plot point away? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers (I got here from HNQ btw)

Answer (score 18):

She couldn't leave the game in *Wreck-It Ralph* because of Turbo messing with her code. This made her a glitch, and glitches can't leave the game.

> **King Candy**: Then gamers can choose the racer's avatar. And when they see her glitching and then get glitching in just being herself... They'll think our game is broken. We'll be put out of order for good. All my subjects will be homeless. But there's one who cannot escape because she's a glitch.

> **Sour Bill**: Vanellope was a racer until King Candy tried to delete her code!
>
> **Ralph**: Tried to delete her code? So that's why she's a glitch!

However, after Vanellope crosses the finish line, the game resets and she's no longer a glitch.

> **Sour Bill**: He'll do anything to keep her from racing. Because if she crosses the finish line, the game will reset and she won't be a glitch anymore!

She chose to maintain the ability zip around like a glitch, but she is fundamentally no longer a glitch, so she can leave the game. (Either that, or this is actually her in-game special ability.)

And, as @BinaryWorrior mentioned in the comments, we see Venellope leave her game at the end of *Wreck-It Ralph*, to attend the wedding of Fix-It Felix and Calhoun:

[image: Vanellope wearing her princess dress at the wedding]

See also [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/95677/30306) on Movies & TV Stack Exchange, which parts of this answer were based on.

Comment: I don't believe she *chose* to retain her glitching ability, that appears to be her "special power"